# When discarding a draft, the tab title and similar questions are not discarded

Tags: bug, draft

When you discard a drafted question, its title is not removed from the tab title. Also, the similar questions are not reset:

[image]

I would expect the editor to go back to the original state.

Comment: If you manually clear the title field, they won't be reset either; so that's probably why. It seems to be checking if the title contains at least 3 words before updating the page title and/or searching for similar questions, but looks like there's no logic that handles the case where the title field has been cleared.